# Multiple Data Filtering

Tags: javascript, reactjs, filter

Please help me do the correct multiple filtering, it should be possible to filter by city, tag, and distance, and each category has many items, for example:

Cities: Moscow, St. Petersburg, Kiev, Warsaw, London

Tags: Marathon, Half Marathon, Relay

Distances: 7km, 22km, 100km, 42km

You can mark as many items as you like for filtering

```js
var events = [
{id: 0, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event1", city:"Moscow", distances:"100km", tags:[{id: 0, name: Marathon},{id: 1, name: Half Marathon}]},
{id: 1, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event2", city:"London", distances:"22km", tags:[{id: 0, name: Relay}]},
{id: 2, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event3", city:"Moscow", distances:"42km", tags:[{id: 0, name: Marathon},{id: 1, name: Relay}]},
{id: 3, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event4", city:"Kiev", distances:"100km", tags:[{id: 0, name: Marathon},{id: 1, name: Half Marathon},{id: 2, name: Эстафета}]},
{id: 4, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event5", city:"Warsaw", distances:"42km", tags:[{id: 0, name: Marathon}]},
{id: 5, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event6", city:"St. Petersburg", distances:"22km", tags:[{id: 0, name: Relay},{id: 1, name: Half Marathon}]},
{id: 6, date:"22.12.2019", name:"event7", city:"St. Petersburg", distances:"7km", tags:[{id: 0, name: Half Marathon}]},
]
```

What is the best way to filter this out if, for example, I chose Marathon, Relay, 42km, 100km for filtering, well, you can choose different options
What I tried: I created 3 arrays under the categories of filters, when I click on the items, I wrote it down to the desired array and then I run it like this:

```js
const { filterCity } = this.state; // array of selected filters by city
    const { eventById } = this.props.Events.eventsList.events; // all events
    const allEvents = (eventById === null ? [] : eventById); //data check 
    const filtered = allEvents.filter((events) => {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
      for (let i = 0; i < filterCity.length; i++) {
        // eslint-disable-next-line no-plusplus
        for (let j = 0; j < events.tags.length; j++) {
          if (filterCity.indexOf(events.tags[j].name) !== -1) {
            return false;
          }
        }
      }
      return true;
    });
```

So far, only for filtering cities, but here you can choose what cities you want in different order and there will be norms, but do I do it right, because I want to add this function to other categories right away so that it checks for everything, it turns out a couple more internal cycles, maybe it’s possible to do something better, or please tell me the norms, please

P.S. I'm using the react task purely on js

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do something like this, where you pass your filters as an array of objects with a single key/value pair. You can then filter on those individually and return the event if at least one filter matches.

This should allow you to filter on multiple filter categories, and multiple values within those categories.

```
const filters = [{ city: 'Moscow' }, { city: 'Kiev' }, { distances: '42km'} ];

events.filter(event => {

    // will return true if one of the filtered values is present in the event object
    return filters.some(filter => {
        return hasFilteredProperty(event, filter);
    });

});

// Pass filter as { key: value }
const hasFilteredProperty = (event, filterObj) => {

    const filterKey = Object.keys(filterObj)[0];

    if (filterKey === 'tags') {
        return hasFilteredTags(event, filterObj[filterKey]);
    } else {
        return event[filterKey] === filterObj[filterKey];
    }

}

// Pass filtered tags as an array of names: [ 'Half Marathon', 'Marathon', '100km' ]
const hasFilteredTags = (event, filteredTags) => {

    const eventTagNames = event.tags.map(tag => tag.name);
    return eventTagNames.some(tagName => filteredTags.includes(tagName));

}
```

Comment: ok with a simple object it works, but what about the "tags" field, where there is an array of objects? they also have to go through the filter, but this option does not filter them

Comment: I've updated my answer to include an example, but it really depends on the data structure of your filters, which I currently don't know exactly. Obviously this example doesn't take into account things like case-insensitivity, but it should give you an idea on how to proceed.

Comment: Now it works with tags, but what’s the matter, for example, if we select the city “Moscow” for the filter, and the filter “Half Marathon”, it will display all the events where at least one thing is encountered, but the idea of filters is to choose city "Moscow", and the filter "Half Marathon" should only output where all the filters match in the event

Comment: Hm.. that was not clear from your initial question but in that case you need to modify the matching functions to perform differently. Right now the functions indeed work in such a way that it matches at least one. If you want to match everything you should be able to use `every` instead of `some`

Comment: I replaced all the soms with evry and it doesn’t work, it’s even broken, it only checks for one key, for example, "city", and if there are still "tags" I don’t even look at this key, I checked it in the console

Answer (score 0):

You can use array `includes` function to check if an the city of event exists in the `filterCity`. For other similar property you can do the same. For tag as the event property itself is an array of object you can first create array of tag name using `map` then check if at least one of element in `filterTag` exists. The demo code can be seen below.

```
let filterCity = ['Moscow', 'Russia']
let filterTag = ['Relay','Marathon']
let filteredEvent = events.filter(event => {
  if(filterCity.length && !filterCity.includes(event.city)) return false
   if(filterTag.length && event.tags.map(tag => tag.name).find(tag => filterTag.indexOf(tag)>-1)==undefined) return false
 return true
})

console.log(filteredEvent)
```

Comment: if filterCity will be empty and filterTag = ['Half Marathon','Marathon'] then it will find all the events where there is a Half Marathon or Marathon tag, and only those where there is a Half Marathon and Marathon should be found

Comment: otherwise everything works fine, but with tags it’s not quite right